# Data not appearing in the datagrid Kinect c#

Tags: c#, kinect

I've written the following code to display some data, but the data grid is just appearing empty,
here is my code:

```
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    DataColumn col = new DataColumn("A", typeof(string));
                    col.MaxLength = 100;
                    dt.Columns.Add(col);
                    col = new DataColumn("B", typeof(string));
                    col.MaxLength = 100;
                    dt.Columns.Add(col);
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    dt.Rows.Add(x,y);
                    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: I used it and the grid has data but when i run it it appears just empty rows

Comment: yea, as you can see above, after i defined them i added them to the datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`  in your DataGrid declaration?  e.g.

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" 
    Height="140" Margin="0,5,0,10"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

For more precise control over column definitions, add a `DataGrid.Columns` element:

```
<toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="TheDataGrid"  
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
    <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>         
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Contact Name" Width="SizeToCells"   
                                       Binding="{Binding ContactName}"  
                                       IsReadOnly="False"/> 

        ... more columns
    </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns> 
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```

Comment: It worked thanks alot, the only thing is that the when i try closing the window it seemed not responding and i have to wait for some time, can you advise?

Comment: with that sparse information, it could be lots of things. I Suggest you ask another question. (but the likeihood is something in your code)